# Using kapacitor to snepshot influxdb data to save it from retention policy

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

Can I use kapacitor to save some raw data between specific timestamps from default retention to unlimited one ? For now Im using "SELECT INTO" construction but I think kapacitor  could be more natural.

I know kapacitor is for life processing but may be.